# How can I use unused disk space for my partition?

Tags: partitioning, 18.04

I have surfed the internet prior asking the question but I was not able to find the information on how to use unused disk space when there is only 1 partition. Take a look at my GPartes screen shot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkRmh.png

I cannot extend the /dev/sda1 partition as it is already extended. How can I use all the space on my Ubuntu 18.04?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone faces the same problem as I do, this trick will do:

```
sudo resize2fs /dev/sda1
```

Note that you need to state your own partition name, so replace `/dev/sda1` with yours partition name